# Signalling a condition variable (pthreads)

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, mutex, condition-variable

Suppose some condition variable "cond" is associated with a mutex variable "mutex". If a thread is sleeping on `cond` after calling `pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex)`, and another thread that has `mutex` locked is finished, does it matter whether that thread calls `pthread_cond_signal(&cond)` before or after calling `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)` ? Does it even need to unlock the mutex at all if it calls `pthread_cond_signal(&cond)`, since the sleeping thread will acquire the mutex anyway?

EDIT: According to https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarOverview, "Failing to unlock the mutex after calling pthread_cond_signal() may not allow a matching pthread_cond_wait() routine to complete (it will remain blocked)." I guess then, unlocking, and perhaps only afterwards, is required.

Comment: +1 for answering your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always unlock the mutex after calling `pthread_cond_signal`. Here are some good questions/answers to read:

[Calling pthread_cond_signal without locking mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544234/calling-pthread-cond-signal-without-locking-mutex)

It won't come to me right now, but I'm pretty sure there's a good reason (in terms of race conditions) that you don't want to unlock the mutex before signalling.

Comment: If after signalling the condition variable and unlocking the mutex, the thread immediately calls `pthread_mutex_lock()` on that mutex, is it guaranteed not to starve the threads previously awoken by `pthread_cond_signal()` ?

Comment: @ManRow: There may be such a guarantee in the Priority Scheduling option, if the right priorities are set. Otherwise, definitely not.

Comment: The good reason is avoiding priority inversion: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.programming.threads/msg/a3721a2fc9b21c64?hl=ky linked from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544234/calling-pthread-cond-signal-without-locking-mutex/4544494#4544494

Answer (score 4):

If you keep the mutex locked, then the thread being woken cannot acquire the mutex, so will block in `pthread_cond_wait` waiting to reacquire the mutex.

You do not need to hold the mutex locked to call `pthread_cond_signal`. In fact, if your application logic can work with a signal when the mutex is not locked then that is a better way to do it --- the OS can schedule the waiting thread immediately, and it doesn't have to wait for the signalling thread to unlock the mutex before proceeding.

However, in this scenario care must be taken to ensure that the wake-up is not lost, and you don't have a problem with the "wrong" thread being woken. If you use a straight-forward predicate, this shouldn't be a problem in practice.