# How to use a std::condition_variable correctly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, condition-variable

I'm confused about `conditions_variables` and how to use them (safely). In my application I've a class that makes a gui-thread but while the gui is constructed by the gui-thread, the main thread needs to wait.

The situation is the same as for the function below. The main thread makes a mutex, lock and `condition_variable`. It then makes the thread. While this `worker` `thread` has not passed a certain point (here printing the numbers), the main thread is not allowed to continue (i.e. has to `wait` for all numbers being printed).

How do I use `condition_variables` correctly in this context? Also, I've read that spontaneous wake-ups are an issue. How can I handle them?

```
    int main()
    {
        std::mutex mtx;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        std::condition_variable convar;

        auto worker = std::thread([&]{
            /* Do some work. Main-thread can not continue. */
            for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) std::cout<<i<<" ";
            convar.notify_all(); // let main thread continue
            std::cout<<"\nworker done"<<std::endl;       
        });


        // The main thread can do some work but then must wait until the worker has done it's calculations.
        /* do some stuff */
        convar.wait(lck);
        std::cout<<"\nmain can continue"<<std::endl; // allowed before worker is entirely finished
        worker.join();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically you'd have some observable shared state on whose change you block:

```
bool done = false;
std::mutex done_mx;
std::condition_variable done_cv;

{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(done_mx);

  std::thread worker([&]() {
    // ...
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(done_mx);
    done = true;
    done_cv.notify_one();
  });

  while (true) { done_cv.wait(lock); if (done) break; }

  // ready, do other work

  worker.join();
}
```

Note that you wait in a loop until the actual condition is met. Note also that access to the actual shared state (`done`) is serialized via the mutex `done_mx`, which is locked whenever `done` is accessed.

There's a helper member function that performs the condition check for you so you don't need the loop:

```
done_cv.wait(lock, [&]() { return done; });
```

Comment: Why do you need the lock_guard?

Comment: @dani, to automatically unlock the mutex upon leaving the scope.

Comment: I just wanted to say, never use a lambda with automatic reference capture as a thread function. So. Many. Bugs.

Comment: @ZanLynx: What's the bug?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't think that you have one here, but I've seen so many. For example, adding a use of a variable that isn't protected by a mutex. Using a reference to a stack variable in a function that exited.

Comment: @KerrekSB the `while` loop with `done_cv.wait` is invalid

Comment: @KerrekSB is there a bug in the scope of the `lock_guard`? According to the last answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043049/c11-stdcondition-variable-can-we-pass-our-lock-directly-to-the-notified-thr?rq=1 and the documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable the lock must go out of scope to unlock the mutex before notifying.

Comment: @dani: I think you can notify the CV whenever you like, either while you still hold the lock or after. The notification is just queued up; it can of course only be delivered once the mutex is eventually unlocked.

Comment: @dani It might actually be a bug to unlock the mutex before calling notify_one. See for example this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671238/1487069