# std::condition_variable spurious blocking

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable

As you know, condition variables should be called in cycle to avoid spurious wake-ups. Like this:

```
while (not condition)
    condvar.wait();
```

If another thread wants to wake up waiting thread, it must set condition flag to true. E.g.:

```
condition = true;
condvar.notify_one();
```

I wonder, is it possible for condition variable to be blocked by this scenario:

1)Waiting thread checks condition flag, and finds it is equal to FALSE, so, it's going to enter `condvar.wait()` routine.

2)But just before this (but after condition flag checking) waiting thread is preempted by kernel (e.g. because of time slot expiration).

3) At this time, another thread wants to notify waiting thread about condition. It sets condition flag to TRUE and calls `condvar.notify_one();`

4) When kernel scheduler runs first thread again, it enters `condvar.wait()` routine, but the notification have been already missed.

So, waiting thread can't exit from `condvar.wait()`, despite condition flag is set to TRUE, because there is no wake up notifications anymore.

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do pthreads’ condition variable functions require a mutex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763714/why-do-pthreads-condition-variable-functions-require-a-mutex)

Comment: See also, [Calling pthread_cond_signal without locking mutex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544234/calling-pthread-cond-signal-without-locking-mutex?rq=1)

Comment: @bamboon. Yes, these questions are quite similar. I've just approached this problem by another side.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is exactly why a condition variable must be used in conjunction with a mutex, in order to atomically update the state and signal the change. The full code would look more like:

```
unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex);
while (not condition)
    condvar.wait(lock);
```

and for the other thread:

```
lock_guard<mutex> lock(mutex);
condition = true;
condvar.notify_one();
```

Comment: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all) - don't see where notifying thread locks mutex. Does this page contains error?

Comment: @Vasily That example shows a design flaw, which it circumvents by just sleeping for a second. It could suffer from the problem you are describing. There could be situations where that just wouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes, I see now. If notifying thread has to have access to this mutex, it's an explanation. Thanks. I thought it doesn't.

Comment: I would also mention the fact that class `condition_variable` in C++11 has an overload of the `wait()` member function which accepts a predicate as its second argument, and that internally realizes the loop.

Comment: Why once `std::unique_lock` and once `std::lock_guard`?

Answer (score 4):

You example missing small part, but that explains why that is not possible if done correctly:

```
while (not condition) // when you check condition mutex is locked
    condvar.wait( mutex ); // when you wait mutex is unlocked
```

So if you change condition to true under the same mutex lock, this situation will not happen.

Comment: I doubt it. Notifying thread knows nothing about this mutex, so, it can't be used for access restriction. If I'd call condvar.notify_one(mutex), it would've been correct. But I don't use any mutexes in notifying thread

Comment: @Vasily The point is that the other thread can't notify the waiting thread because it is currently blocked on the mutex.

Comment: Notifying thread changing variable that is protected by this mutex lock, so it has to be aware of the mutex

Comment: @bamboon Why can't it? I don't see, how mutex prevents to send notification

Comment: @Slava Look. Until you call condvar.wait(mutex), condvar doesn't know about mutex existance. So, before waiting thread enters this routine, no way notifying thread can know about this mutex, even if it has access to condvar.

Comment: @Vasily The notifier thread can't propagate and send the notification because it doesn't hold the mutex and it can't acquire it because the waiting thread holds it and that one will only release it once it is in `wait`.

Comment: @Vasily: Whoever signals the condvar should be doing it under the same mutex. This eliminates the wake/wait race completely. If your mutex isn't known to the notifying thread, what is it protecting, exactly?

Comment: Yes, I understand now. It looks like notifying thread has to lock the same mutex before notify_one call. Manual I've read missed this part.

Comment: @Vasily I am not sure if notify_one has to be called under mutex, but changing condition variable (not condvar) definately requires mutex, and that does not have to be in documentation. Another problem that some people are changing bool or int on intel platform without proper lock, assuming it is safe, but that not quite correct.

Comment: @Slava Right, it looks like I don't have to lock notify_one. Only condition.

Answer (score 2):

Mike Seymour his answer is incomplete because there is a race condition which ends up with wakeup lost.
The right way is to (now with the c++11) is as follow:

Thread1:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(myMutex);
condvar.wait(lck, []{ return condition; }); // prevent spurious wakeup
// Process data
```

Thread2:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(myMutex);
    condition = true;
} // unlock here! prevent wakeup lost
condvar.notify_one();
```