# why the action is different when pthread_cond_signal in a loop or not in a loop

Tags: c, linux

Today I learn pthread,I write a toy example about the producer and consumer problem.But I find the program's action is different when I put the **pthread_cond_signal in a loop or not in a loop**.Here is the original code.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int good_count = 0;
int total = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mt;
pthread_cond_t cv;
volatile int producer_wait = 1;

void* produce()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);
    printf("Producer Wait;\n");
    producer_wait = 1;
    pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mt);
    producer_wait = 0;
    printf("Received a signal\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* consume()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);
    while(producer_wait)
    {
        pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
        sleep(1);
    }
    //pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[2];
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    /*initialize mutex and cond */
    pthread_mutex_init(&mt, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cv, NULL);

    /*initialize thread attribute*/
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    pthread_create(&threads[0], &attr, produce, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], &attr, consume, NULL);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mt);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cv);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The producer thread  block in pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mt),the consumer thread call pthread_cond_signal(&cv) in a while loop does not take effect.But if I modify the consume() function code like this,then it take effects.

```
void* consume()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);

    /*while(producer_wait)
    {
        pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
        sleep(1);
    }*/
    pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I am very puzzled, hoping to get answers!

I modify the consume function,**move pthread_mutex_lock(&mt) and pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt) into the while loop,and comment the sleep(1)**, the consumer can release the mutex.In this way,the producer thread can receive the signal. But if I **uncomment sleep(1)**,the producer thread can't receive the signal.Why?

```
void* consume()
{
    while(producer_wait)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);
        pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
        //sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

the consumer thread

Comment: A consumer should wait, the producer should signal.

Comment: For discussion on [pthread_cond_signal()][1] view it.[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544234/calling-pthread-cond-signal-without-locking-mutex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with loop, your consumer never releases the mutex, and the producer requires the mutex to continue, so deadlock

Comment: Thanks a lot.I append a question in the last.

Comment: the consumer sleeps while holding the lock, makes the producer staving. and the consumer acquires the lock as soon as releasing the lock, the producer has no chance to run